# A question about Laplace law

Tags: forces, pressure, elasticity, surface-tension, bubbles

In Laplace law, the force on a soap bubble from inside is $F = P.πr^2$ and what I understand that the leaning forces acting on the inside of the sphere are resolved into two components the vertical ones cancel each other and remain the horizontal component but then the forces acting on inside the bubble won't be equal . Why did Laplace assume that horizontal forces are acting by the same magnitude as the original leaning forces on the horizontal projection ($πr^2$) of the hemisphere?

Edit: see [Laplace law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/surten2.html) at F downwards

Comment: it does not seem right, can you give a reference to read the original?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I edited the question

Comment: I agree with you, it does not seem to make sense, but perhaps there is some justification, let us wait for an answer

Comment: If you do an overall force balance on the hemisphere of gas, the integrated pressure force from the surface must be equal to the upward force acting on the bottom of the hemisphere.

Comment: @ChetMiller so what you mean is that if used integration to find out the total force acting on the hemisphere it would be equal to assuming that an average force Equals $p.πr^2$  acts on every point of the hemisphere then measuring the total force

Comment: I think that that says what I mean.